# Newbie How do I send Json information using scriptsharp to a web service

Tags: json, script#

I have modified the sample Demo to try to send a json object rather than a string.  The web site see it as a string of value [object] rather than Json text. What do I need to change.

```
namespace DemoScript {
// [Imported]
// [IgnoreNamespace]
public sealed class Person 
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

[GlobalMethods]
internal static class HelloPage {

    static HelloPage() {
        // Add script that runs on startup as the script is loaded into
        // the page

        Element helloButton = Document.GetElementById("helloButton");

        Person p = new Person();

        helloButton.AddEventListener("click", delegate(ElementEvent e) {
            InputElement nameTextBox = Document.GetElementById("nameTextBox").As<InputElement>();

            p.FirstName = nameTextBox.Value;
            p.LastName = "Surname";

            XmlHttpRequest xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
//          xhr.Open(HttpVerb.Get, "/HelloService.ashx?name=" +   nameTextBox.Value.EncodeUriComponent());
            xhr.Open(HttpVerb.Get, "/HelloService.ashx?name=" + p);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I pass p.FisrtName it all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to JSON encode your object first. In Script# native JSON is mapped to `System.Serialization.Json`, which has methods `Stringify()` and `Parse()`.

Documentation on native JSON: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON.

For support for browsers without native JSON, you can include this popular script: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DuckMaestro I have it working now.

Just in case this is useful to some other beginner the code changes are:

```
p.FirstName = nameTextBox.Value;
p.LastName = "Surname";
XmlHttpRequest xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
string text = Json.Stringify(p);
xhr.Open(HttpVerb.Get, "/HelloService.ashx?name=" + text);
```

Comment: You should probably encode the query string parameter. Make that text.EncodeUriComponent()